# What directory is used for Zend plugins?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Let's say I have the following in my ini file:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.auth = AuthPlugin
```

Where should the AuthPlugin class be placed?  Let's say I would like it under controllers/plugins.

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestions below I am still having trouble.  Let me be exact in what I currently have:

1) main part of application.ini

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.view[] =
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.plugins.authplugin.class = "AuthPlugin"
```

2) my Bootstrap.php has nothing (I had lots of things in there, but still get the error with nothing):

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
}
```

3) I have an AuthPlugin.php class in application/plugins directory

```
class AuthPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
        { 
           // code here
        }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AuthPlugin' not found in C:\[my dir structure here]\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php on line 111
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious here.  Thanks in advance.  Zend Framework 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I register a plugin named Foo_Plugin_SuperDuperPlugin in my application config:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.superduperplugin.class = "Foo_Plugin_SuperDuperPlugin"
```

The plugin is located at
`APPLICATION_PATH/plugins/Foo_Plugin_SuperDuperPlugin.php` and is autoloaded from there because the [Resource Module Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module) automatically looks in that (recommended) location for plugin type resources.  If I wanted to load the plugin from, say,
`APPLICATION_PATH/controllers/plugins/Foo_Plugin_SuperDuperPlugin.php` then I would register a new resource loader with the autoloader and define a type of resource named 'plugin' and the path to those plugin resources.  So in my bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
            'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace'     => 'Foo',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'plugin' => array(
                    'path'      => 'controllers/plugins',
                    'namespace' => 'Plugin',
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

and then I need to ensure that this method is bootstrapped before the SuperDuperPlugin is registered (which, in this example, happens when the application config is read `resources.frontcontroller.plugins.superduperplugin.class = ...`).  This can be achieved by placing the `_initAutoloader` method at the top of the bootstrap.php or by calling `$this->bootstrap('autoLoader');` from any other _init method, before the frontController resource is initialised.

UPDATED: Try adding this to your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
            'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'plugin' => array(
                    'path'      => 'controllers/plugins',
                    'namespace' => '',
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

and maybe even leave off the namespace.  Or: add `appnamespace = "Foo"` to your config and rename the class to `Foo_Plugin_AuthPlugin`.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, because I can't get this to work.  I am updating the original question with more details.

Comment: I could get it working with the resource addition, but I finally did get it working with a basic require 'controllers/AuthPlugin.php'; (or whatever dir I put it in) into the _initAutoloader() method.

Comment: I meant couldn't above (in terms of using Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource) but could using a basic require.

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with using a require directive. Still, it seems to me that yours is a naming issue - the class should certainly be named differently if you want it to be loaded from APPLICATION_PATH/plugins - it should be named Plugin_AuthPlugin and it might also need another prefix (ZF examples usually go for 'My_' and I was using 'Foo_' in my examples), but that depends on what prefix (or 'namespace') your autoloaders are configured to hunt for.

Comment: I finally got this working.  There's actually an issue I believe in the documentation that someone else pointed out.  You must use a namespace - whereas I was trying not to use one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

hmm am having the exact same issue in zf 1.11. It seems the autoloader does not exists before the plugins get loaded :s

Answer (score 0):

I think in /application/plugins/

But you could also set another Directory for it.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.  It may be that my autoloading isn't working right for this type of class, but it can't find my AuthPlugin class whether I put it under application/plugins or controllers.

Comment: did you also bootstrapped the plugin by registrering it?

Comment: resources.frontController.pluginDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH"/plugins"

Comment: I don't have it bootstrapped (I thought it only needed to be in the ini file).  The .pluginDirectory setting doesn't seem to help (also I thought I read somewhere that this ini setting was proposed and not implemented yet).

Answer (score 0):

Since the application will bootstrap itself from the config file after registering the Autoloader, you should put AuthPlugin.php (which should contain the AuthPlugin class) in the include path.

Comment: I tried this but I can't get it working. I updated the description with lots more information.  Maybe you can spot what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I've just been searching around for ages for a solution to autoloading plugins outside of the library and have finally figured it out. Generally, I have been writing generic plugins to use across many different projects and keeping them in the library made sense, providing you follow the standard ZF naming conventions these will autoload anyway. Recently, I was writing a project specific plugin and I wanted to keep it somewhere within my application directory, but how to autoload? I've never found that using the "application/plugins" directory worked. Hopefully this might benefit someone else:

If you are using a modular directory structure then rather than using the "application/plugins" directory you can use "application/module_name/plugins". You can then take advantage of the [Module Resource Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module), which is a massively useful and underused part of ZF. If you set it up in your bootstrap, by default it is set up to autoload a whole bunch of stuff including forms, models and (I discovered today) plugins. You can also define your own custom resource types. For example below is an _initAutoloader function from a bootstrap in a project which has a default and admin module and a custom 'vo' resource type contained in the admin module:

```
public function _initAutoLoader() {
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

    $defaultLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
        array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'
        )
    );

    $adminLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
        array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin',
        )
    );

    $adminLoader->addResourceTypes(
        array(
            'vo' => array(
                'path'      => 'models/vo',
                'namespace' => 'Vo',
            )
        )
    );

    $autoloader->pushAutoloader($defaultLoader);
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader($adminLoader);
}
```

Here I have two modules, default and admin. Assuming the following directory structure:

```
application/default/forms/FooForm.php
application/default/models/FooModel.php
application/default/plugins/FooPlugin.php
application/admin/forms/FooForm.php
application/admin/models/FooModel.php
application/admin/models/vo/FooVo.php
application/admin/plugins/FooPlugin.php
```

I can autoload across any module just by instantiating an object of each class:

```
new Form_FooForm();
new Model_FooModel();
new Plugin_FooPlugin(); // or add plugin to application.ini
new Admin_Form_FooForm();
new Admin_Model_FooModel();
new Admin_Vo_FooVo(); // custom resource type
new Admin_Plugin_FooPlugin(); // or add plugin to application.ini
```